# Can an object of the class 'contract' or a class that inherits 'contract' be created in the cpp file of the contract we are making?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, dapp

Can an object of the class 'contract' or a class that inherits 'contract' be created in the cpp file of the contract we are making?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. You can then use it as a normal C++ class. If you use a function that changes persistent memory then it will also change it in the current instantiation of the contract.

Comment: Does this mean that many contracts can be created from a single contract?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe! I'll try it when I have a little more time and let you know unless someone beats me to it